# Open Chrome profile selenium with C# not working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want open a Chrome profile in selenium with C# but its not working. Please help me.
This my code:

````
this.options.AddArgument("user-data-directory=C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
this.options.AddArgument("profile-directory=Profile 25");
this.options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options); //<-Add your path
this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");```
````

Comment: Any error message you got ?

Comment: It only open Default profile not open Profile 25

Comment: What is an error?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
```

instead of

```
this.options.AddArgument("user-data-directory=C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\");
```